# Android Google Maps - Marker Colour Coding only works for last Firestore results

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an Android application which uses Cloud Firestore records to plot markers on a Google Map.

The markers plot as expected. However, when I try to colour code them only the last records are being coloured correctly. For example, if I have two records which need to be coloured "HUE_BLUE", only the second one is coloured correctly and the first is coloured in the default option in my loop (HUE_RED).

Below is the code I have used to generate the map markers and to colour code the markers:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    firebase.collection("PointsOfInterest").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot doc2:queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                poiAddress_id = doc2.getLong("address_id").intValue();
            }
        }
    });

    firebase.collection("Events").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            for(DocumentSnapshot doc3:queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                eventAddress_id = doc3.getLong("address_id").intValue();
            }
        }
    });

    firebase.collection("Address").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        LatLng marker;
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot doc:queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                latitude = doc.getDouble("address_latitude");   //Obtains the latitude for a given address
                longitude = doc.getDouble("address_longitude"); //Obtains the longitude for a given address
                address_id = doc.getLong("address_id").intValue();
                addressName = doc.getString("address_name");
                addressSuburb = doc.getString("address_suburb");
                addressState = doc.getString("address_state");
                addressPostcode = doc.getLong("address_postcode").intValue();
                docID = doc.getId();   //Obtains the name of the specific data record - this is used to label the marker
                marker = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);    //Creates a map marker utilising the latitude and longitude values retrieved from the database

                if (address_id == poiAddress_id) {
                    markerColour = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE;
                } else if (address_id == eventAddress_id) {
                    markerColour = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW;
                } else {
                    markerColour = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED;
                }

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker).title(docID).snippet(addressName + " " + addressSuburb + ", " + addressState + " " + addressPostcode)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(markerColour)));


        }
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions as to why this may be occurring would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure both of your objects meet the condition: `address_id == poiAddress_id`?

Comment: Positive. That was my initial thought for this but that wasn’t it.

Comment: What is the value of `address_id` and `poiAddress_id` on every iteration? I'm sure that you are not getting the same values since different parts of the if statement are triggered, right?